# ruby on rails using scope in a pick list

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I have a code table called priorities.  The table has a boolean called archive.  I have a request table and it's form contains a pick list of priorities.  I'm using scope statements to tell if a priority is archived or not.  This is the code in the model:

```
scope :archived, where(:archive => true)
scope :active, where(:archive => false)
```

I'm trying to use the scope in the request form like this:

```
        <%= f.association :priority, :label_method => :prioritycode.active, :label => 'Priority' %>
```

But, that doesn't work.

What should I be using in the form?

Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I may be missing something -- not familiar with the `association` helper you're using.

If you want a drop-down select list, I would do something like

```
<%= f.collection_select :priority, Priority.active, :id, :name %>
```

(Assumes you have a model `Priority` in which the scope `:active` is defined, and that a priority has a `name`.  Your mileage may vary.)

Comment: The f.association comes from using simple_form.

Answer (score 0):

tharrison post got me thinking (thanks) - this worked:

```
        <%= f.association :priority, :collection => Priority.active.all, :label_method => :prioritycode, :label => 'Priority' %>
```